# Finite series with negative indexing

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How can I approach proving that for all $n,i \in \mathbb{N}$:
$$
\sum_{i = 1-n}^{n} \dfrac{2i+1}{2i-1} = 2n
$$
I have some intuition regarding the fact that the limit of the series is intimately connected to the fact that the difference between the first term of the series and the last term, is:
$$
|n-(1-n)| = 2n-1
$$
I also thought about proving that there is some kind of cancellation happening within the summation, where all values cancel except two of them which sum up to $2n$. But  I struggle with pinning the exact way it could be presented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\sum_{i = 1-n}^{n} \dfrac{2i+1}{2i-1} = \sum_{i=1}^n\left(\dfrac{2i+1}{2i-1}+\dfrac{2(1-i)+1}{2(1-i)-1}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^n\dfrac{4i-2}{2i-1}=2n
$$

Comment: Nice and elegant, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hint

The problem **immediately** succumbs to induction.

**Addendum** In response to comment

By inspection, the conjecture is true for $n=2.$

It is merely required to show that as $n=N$ shifts to $n=(N+1)$,
the additional two terms sum to 2.

With $n=(N+1), the two added terms are (a) and (b), where :

(a)
$i = 1 - (N+1)$ yields $\frac{2(1-N-1) + 1}{2(1 - N - 1) - 1}
= \frac{2 - 2N - 1}{2 - 2n - 3} = \frac{-(2N - 1)}{-(2N + 1)}.$

(b)
$i = (N+1)$ yields $\frac{2(N+1)+1}{2(N+1)-1} = \frac{2N+3}{2N+1}.$

Comment: If it is so obvious and I could not spot it, a short demonstration would be helpful here.

Answer (score 1):

Make the change of index $i=k-n$ so we have

$$\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{2(k-n)+1}{2(k-n)-1}=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\big(1-\frac{2}{2n-2k+1}\big)$$
$$=(1-\frac{2}{2n-1})+(1-\frac{2}{2n-3})+..+(1-\frac{2}{1})+(1-\frac{2}{-1})+...+(1-\frac{2}{3-2n})+(1-\frac{2}{1-2n})$$

So you can see that every term of the form $-\frac{2}{2n-2k+1}$ cancels with one another, leaving us with a sum of $1$'s ($2n$ times), thus we have:
$$\sum_{i=1-n}^{n}\frac{2i+1}{2i-1}=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{2(k-n)+1}{2(k-n)-1}=2n.$$